# Excel VBA: make calculations with data from a form before submitting to database

Tags: excel, vba

I have built an excel VBA form where the user fills in some fields.
I would like to have some calculations made when clicking on the "Calc" button and display the results on the form.

example:

In my form frmForm, I have following TextBoxes defined via (name):
txtA
txtB
txtC

Then, I would like to do some calculations:

```
Sub Calc()
    Dim Result, X, Y As Long
    X = .txtA.Value
    Y = .txtB.Value
    
    Result = X * Y
    With frmFrom
        .txtC = Result
    End With
                
End Sub
```

This does not seem to work... Nothing gets displayed in my form, and no result is sent back...

Comment: Is your calc-routine called at all? In design-node, make a double click on the button. It should show you a routine like `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` (depending on the *name* of the button, not it's capture). From there, call your routine. - Note that you will get a nasty runtime error if one of the textboxes contain non-numeric values. And a small hint: You need to specify the data type for every variable: `Dim Result As Long, X As Long, Y As Long`

Comment: Also, your `With frmFrom` line needs to be ***before*** your `X = .txtA.Value` line.